# Object of type is not JSON serializable

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

Just started with Django Rest framework and following the great tutorial:
https://sunscrapers.com/blog/ultimate-tutorial-django-rest-framework-part-1/

I have created a test model:

*models.py*

```
class Test(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    age = models.IntegerField
```

And to make the object available through the API, I have implemented a serializer. This would serialize to XML, YAML or JSON, the latter is what I am interested in. Below is my serialization class.

*serializers.py*

```
class TestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Test
        fields = ('name', 'age')
```

*app/views.py*

```
class TestViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Test.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.TestSerializer
```

However, it doesn't seem to serialize to JSON as expected as the error below shows:

```
File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type type is not JSON serializable
```

Worth adding, that it worked for like 2 hours then just went bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed a pair of parentheses in your `Test` class's `age` field:

```
class Test(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    age = models.IntegerField()  # <-- missed this pair
```

Comment: Awesome, that was indeed the issue. Just to add to @Reza answer, I added the missing parentheses and got the statement below:

`You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'age' to test without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).`

So I added a default value to the age Integer:
`age = models.IntegerField(default=50)`.


All good now!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would be useful to anyone but I ran into the same issue and mine was a trailing comma(,) at the end of that line.